# Efficient way to setup Jenkins for Automation Project

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, automated-tests

I have configured Jenkins server on windows computer. The systems has below configurations:

> **OS** : Windows 10
>
> **Processor** : intel i3 processor
>
> **RAM** : 16GB
>
> 500GB hard disk

The problem is recently the system get crashed and now windows is unable to start. Lastly, I set up an automated test execution on 3 parallel Chrome browser instances in GUI mode for 2 hours. It gets crashed during the execution. I'm not sure whether this happened due to a lack of sufficient resources or these are adequate configuration resources to handle the execution.

Can someone please share the realistic configuration required to handle such a situation or manage the resources in an efficient way. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe if you can run same tests inside docker then this issue should not come..